# Hugo-ish way to refer to a static file (resource) _indirectly_ so filename can be changed in one place and all content links change

Tags: hugo

I want to have a file, in `/static` that I update every once in awhile.  For example, my resume. The actual filename will have a date in it, e.g. `resume-2021-04-28.pdf`.  It will be referred to in multiple places, e.g., posts that refer directly to it, in header or footer templates, etc.  So I'd like all those references to use a single ... thing ... an easy-to-type thing ... to refer to, say `resume`, and then somewhere I have a ... thing ... that maps `resume` to the current file name `resume-2021-04-28.pdf`.

Oh, and the posts that refer to this are in varied locations (as described above) so page bundles won't work.  I think.

Not sure whether this is done with site params, or a partial, or what.  What's the Hugo-ish way to do it?